# How to create different registration forms for different roles in FOSUserBundle for Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, bundle

I have two different roles, that need different registration forms. I can't find the way to solve this. 
In my config.yml I have

```
fos_user:
db_driver: orm
firewall_name: main
user_class: Main\UserBundle\Entity\User
registration:
    form:
        type: main_user_registration
        handler: main_user.form.handler.registration
```

but if i can't have another form_type. 
Can you give me a hint about what should I do? (I'm just learning Symfony2 so I am new to its architecture).
Thanks

Comment: How do you define which role user should be assigned BEFORE he registered?

Comment: I sent an array with all the roles in the constructor of the forms, and than I can specify in the form which role i want to use. I haven't done it yet, but if I have the role, it's not hard to persist it, I think. The array with the roles are in the service %security.role_hierarchy.roles% and I put it in UserBundle service.yml

Comment: let me know how you got on with this